# Which Ubuntu version for Lenovo T510?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

I'm considering purchase of a refurbished Lenovo ThinkPad T510 with Intel Core2 Duo i5-520M processor.

4GB RAM, 
250GB HDD, 
Intel integrated Graphics

I know it meets minimum hardware requirements. Which Ubuntu version (32 or 64 bit?) would be best for this machine? The Ubuntu desktop certified hardware page for the Thinkpad T510 only mentions Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add RAM and Disk capacity please.

Comment: Whatever you feel that works. Ubuntu is free. Install any version and see what you like. By the way: we do not provide hardware recommedations ;)

Answer (score 0):

64 Bit Operating System will be supported by your system without any issues. It always better to use 64 bit OS over 32 bit has it has better performance, moreover it will also allow you have maximum utilization of resources (RAM).